# Possible positions of the knight after moving $n$ steps in Chessboard.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, chessboard, knight-tours

**Problem**
There is a knight on an infinite chessboard. After moving one step, there are $8$ possible positions, and after moving two steps, there are $33$ possible positions. The possible position after moving n steps is $a_n$, find the formula for $a_n$.

---

I found this sequence is http://oeis.org/A118312

But I can't understand this Recurrence Relation

$$a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 3a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}, \quad\quad n\geq3$$

Can someone give the intuition for this relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### An intuitive setup

The growth of the number of knight moves for $n \ge 3$ can be modelled by an octagon increasing linearly in size, simulated below

[image]

*Simulation taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1093185/1044958).*

We will use the following image to construct the recurrence relation.

[image]

In the image above,
$$a_n = \text{black points + red points + green points + blue points}$$
$$a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} = (\text{black points + red points + green points}) - (\text{black points + red points}) = \text{green points}$$
$$a_{n-3} = \text{black points}$$

Hence, the relation is equivalent to proving
$$3\cdot\text{green points} + \text{black points} = \text{black points + red points + green points + blue points}$$
$$\iff 2\cdot\text{green points} = \text{red points + blue points}$$

As the growth of the number of points is linear, we have
$$a = \text{red points}$$
$$a + d = \text{green points}$$
$$a + 2d = \text{blue points}$$

It holds that
$$2(a + d) = a + (a + 2d)$$

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Mordechai Katzman demonstrates in section $3$ of his paper [Counting monomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504113) (pages $5$ - $8$) that

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
          1 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \; \, n = 0 \\
          8 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \; \, n = 1 \\ 
         33 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad n = 2 \\
1 + 4n + 7n^2 \quad \; \, n \ge 3
     \end{cases}$$

We can now prove by induction that
$$a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 3a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} = 1 + 4n + 7n^2, \quad\quad n\geq3 \tag{1}$$

To test whether $(1)$ holds for $n \ge 3$, we need to define

$$a_0 = 1 + 4(0) + 7(0)^2 = 1$$
$$a_1 = 1 + 4(1) + 7(1)^2 = 12$$
$$a_2 = 1 + 4(2) + 7(2)^2 = 37$$

For the base cases, we have

$$a_3 = 3a_2 - 3a_1 + a_0 = 3\cdot37 - 3\cdot12 + 1 = 1 + 4(3) + 7(3)^2 = 76$$
$$a_4 = 3a_3 - 3a_2 + a_1 = 3\cdot76 - 3\cdot37 + 12 = 1 + 4(4) + 7(4)^2 = 129$$
$$a_5 = 3a_4 - 3a_3 + a_2 = 3\cdot129 -3\cdot76 + 37 = 1 + 4(5) + 7(5)^2 =196$$

Now, we must prove using $(1)$ that $$a_{n+1} = 3a_n - 3a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} = 1 + 4(n+1) + 7(n+1)^2 = 7n^2 + 18n + 12$$

Substituting for $a_n, a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, we get
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &= 3\left(1 + 4n + 7n^2\right) -3\left(1 + 4(n-1) + 7(n-1)^2\right) + \left(1 + 4(n-2) + 7(n-2)^2\right)\\
& = 7n^2 + 18n + 12
\end{align}

$\blacksquare$

Comment: It seems like the heavy lift here is coming up with the value of $a_n$ in the first place. Once you have it, you can show it satisfies the recurrence. Do you have any insights into where $a_n$ comes from?

Comment: @templatetypedef See my new answer.

Comment: @templatetypedef In the context of this answer, $a_n$ comes from the paper I cited.